# How to prove the following about a group G?

Tags: group-theory

How does one prove that:

> for all $a\in G$, where $G$ is a group (not necessarily abelian) $a^{|G|} = 1_G$.

Comment: [I wish I knew](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory) how to prove that *without* using Lagrange's theorem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, your restrict yourself to finite groups (otherwise, the statement does not make sense).

Then, you apply Lagrange's Theorem to the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ to conclude that the order of $a$ divides $|G|$.

Comment: thanks .. This theorem is exactly wat i need !

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard fact, which i think is proved in All abstract algebra books. Here is the proof, given in the book by Herstein. See **Corollary 2**.

**Corollary 1:** If $G$ is a finite group, and $a \in G$, then $o(a) \mid o(G)$.

**Proof.** Consider the cyclic subgroup generated by $a$, consisting of $a,a^{2},a^{3},\cdots,$.  Since $a^{o(a)}=e$, therefore, this subgroup has atmost $o(a)$ elements. If it has fewer elements, then $a^{i}=a^{j}$, for some integers $0 \leq i < j < o(a)$. Then $a^{j-i}=e$, yet $0< j-i < o(a)$, which contradicts the meaning of $o(a)$. Thus the cyclic subgroup generated by $a$ has $o(a)$ elements, and hence by Lagrange's theorem $o(a) \mid o(G)$.

**Corollary 2:** If $G$ is a finite group and $a \in G$, then $a^{o(G)}=e$.

**Proof.** By *Corollary 1*, we have $o(a) \mid o(G)$ which implies $o(G)=k \cdot o(a)$, therefore $a^{o(G)}=a^{k \cdot o(a)} = (a^{o(a)})^{k} = e^{k}=e$.

Comment: Note that Corollaries 1 and 2 are actually equivalent. I wish I knew a proof of them that does not depend on Lagrange's Theorem. (There is a nice one in the case of abelian groups.)

Comment: @lhf: Yeah, more or less. Ok could you please cite the reference for  the abelian groups case. I haven't seen it, so would be interesting.

Comment: It's a proof that is frequently used to prove Fermat's little theorem in number theory books: consider the map $x \mapsto ax$. This is a bijection. Hence $g_1 \cdots g_n = (a g_1) \cdots (a g_n) = a^n g_1 \cdots g_n$. Now cancel $g_1 \cdots g_n$. See for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Second_method