# Let $G$ be a group, $x∈G$, $ a,b∈\Bbb Z$ and $a⊥b$. If $x^a=x^b$, then $x=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

There is a missing step in this proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106292/135812

> ### Lemma
>
> Let $G$ be a group, $x\in G$, $a,b\in \mathbb Z$ and $a\perp b$. If $x^a = x^b$, then $x=1$.
>
> *Proof*: by Bezout's lemma, some $k,\ell\in\mathbb Z$ exist, such that $ak+b\ell=1$. Then
>   $$ x = x^{ak+b\ell} = (x^a)^k \cdot (x^b)^\ell = 1^k \cdot 1^\ell = 1 $$

To my view it the fact that $x^a = 1$ and $x^b = 1$ is pulled out the air. I would like to try fix this. 
Thanks!

Comment: It's not true if $x^a=x^b$ **only**. For example, in a cyclic group $C_{10}$, then $x^3=x^{13}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One needs $x^a=x^b=1$. This is what was actually meant in the Lemma, I think.

Answer (score 2):

This lemma is not true.

Take $G=\Bbb Z_{16}^*$, $x=\bar 5$, $a=3$, $b=11$.

Then, $x^3=\bar 5^3=\overline{125}=\overline{13}$, and $x^{11}=\overline{48828125}=\overline{13}$