# Any group which is of prime order is a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I don't know how to prove this:

> Any group which is of prime order is a cyclic group.

What fact should I use to prove this?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106163/show-that-every-group-of-prime-order-is-cyclic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose $|G|=p$ where $p$ is a prime.

Suppose, $a\in G$. What can you say about $|a|$?

Note $|.|$ denotes order.

Comment: the order of $a$ must divide the order of group using the lagrange's theorem.. hence it can be $1$ or $p$.. but why shouldn't it be $1$..

Comment: @spectraa: But can all the $p$ **(>1)** elements of group $G$ have order $1$?

Comment: but we are considering just $1$ element..

Comment: Yes, we are. But I'm trying to prove that there **will** be an element of order $p$. There **will** be an element such that the order $\ne$1. Since we reach a contradiction if this is not the case.

Comment: @spectraa Just change it in “Suppose $a\in G$, $a\ne1$.”

Comment: @Swapnil I understood ,you mean that we are proving for any general element $a$ of $G$ ,so we should not consider special case of $a=1$..is it what you mean to say..

Comment: @spectraa Yes. But do you understand the reasoning? :)

Comment: @spectraa: As egreg says you can directly assume $a\ne \text{identity}$ (since identity is unique) and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

1. Take a nonzero element a in the group.
2. Consider the group generated by a, which is of course cyclic.
3. Try to recall what  you can say about the order of a subgroup relative to the order of the group itself, and what  this implies in your case.