# Prove that a group with $3$ elements is cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Prove that a group with $3$ elements is cyclic.

I tried the case where $G=\{e,a,b\}
$
and I kept trying multiplication 
and finally I found that 
$a^2$ must equal to $b$ and $b^2$ must equal to $a$. 
Then $a^3=e$.

Are there any other methods
?
I have another question :

> Prove that a group with $4$ elements may or may not be cyclic.

Comment: Another method is to use the Lagrange's Theorem. Using Lagrange Theorem, you can prove that any group of prime order is cyclic.

Comment: I think that it doesn't take a lot of work to prove that any group of order $4$ (note that I omitted the word “finite”; are you aware of some *infinite* group of order $4$?) may by cyclic or not.

Comment: I recommend to read my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570641/every-group-with-5-elements-is-an-abelian-group. A similar method works for a group of 4 elements.

Comment: @ThomasShelby: you mean Cauchy's theorem, right? Lagrange's theorem only gives $o(g)\mid o(G)$, while Cauchy's theorem ensures $o(G)=p\Longrightarrow\exists g:o(g)=p$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I meant something like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024091/any-group-which-is-of-prime-order-is-a-cyclic-group).

Comment: @ThomasShelby: all right, I get it. Since the identity is unique and $o(g)\mid o(G)$, in a group with prime order all the elements except the identity are generators, fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), a group with 3 elements can have only the trivial subgroups. Because 3 is prime only 1 and 3 divide it. So, only possible subgroups are $\{e\}$ with one element and $G$ with three. For $x \in G$ that is not $e$ a group generated with this element,
$<x>$ must be whole $G$. So $G$ is cyclic.

A group with 4 elements can have untrivial subgroups as 4 isn't prime. For instance $\mathbb{Z_4} = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ with $+$ is cyclic. It is generated with the element $1$.        But group $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2} = \{(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)\}$ with $+$ defined as $(a, b) + (a', b') = (a + a', b + b')$ is not cyclic.

Comment: can you explaine in more terms  " For x∈G that is not e a group generated with this element,
<x> must be whole G. So G is cyclic."

Comment: We can take any element (that is not the unit $e$) $x \in G$ and by multiplying it with itself, we will get every other element of this group. So let $x \in G$. $x x$ is another element that must be in the group but is different from $x$ since we said $x$ is not a unit. So, now we have three distinct elements: $e, x, x^2$. We also know, that since our group can only have either one or three elements, $x^2$ can not be the unit.  Now we have the whole $G$.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of “keeping multiplying” it's easier to fill the Cayley diagram: in every row and column every element must appear.

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
  & e & a & b \\ \hline
e & e & a & b \\
a & a & \\
b & b & \\
\end{array}
In the slot corresponding to $a^2$ you cannot put $e$, because otherwise the slot for $ab$ would contain $b$. Hence $a^2=b$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
  & e & a & b \\ \hline
e & e & a & b \\
a & a & b\\
b & b & \\
\end{array}
and now the diagram has a unique completion
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
  & e & a & b \\ \hline
e & e & a & b \\
a & a & b & e \\
b & b & e & a\\
\end{array}
Then $a^3=a^2a=ba=e$.

You can try your hand with a four element group and see that the diagram admits different completions.

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  & e & a & b & c \\ \hline
e & e & a & b & c \\
a & a & \\
b & b & \\
c & c &
\end{array}
In the slot for $a^2$ we can put any of $e$, $b$ or $c$. Let's try with $e$:
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  & e & a & b & c \\ \hline
e & e & a & b & c \\
a & a & e\\
b & b & \\
c & c &
\end{array}
Then we are forced to put in the following
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  & e & a & b & c \\ \hline
e & e & a & b & c \\
a & a & e & c & b \\
b & b & c\\
c & c & b
\end{array}
For $b^2$ we can have either $e$ or $c$. Let's try $e$:
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  & e & a & b & c \\ \hline
e & e & a & b & c \\
a & a & e & c & b \\
b & b & c & e\\
c & c & b &
\end{array}
Now we can complete:
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  & e & a & b & c \\ \hline
e & e & a & b & c \\
a & a & e & c & b \\
b & b & c & e & a\\
c & c & b & a & e
\end{array}
It would be very tedious to verify that this diagram indeed produces a group. It does and is the product of two cyclic groups of order two; it is also the subgroup of $S_4$ given by $\{id,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$.

Comment: I need another proof, without using the Cayley diagram

Comment: @ElMouden Then using Lagrange's theorem is what you need.

Comment: Oh Thanks Finally i did it