# Show that a group $G$ so that the order of the quotient group is $| G/C(G) | = 37$ doesn't exist.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

Show that a group $G$ so that the order of the quotient group is  $| G/C(G) | = 37$ doesn't exist.

I guess $C(G)$ here means the center of the group, I am not sure because this is an exam question from a previous year. 
I tried by using Lagrange's theorem but don't know where to go from there. Any hint helps! Thanks.

Comment: $37{}$ is prime.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  which means what? Sorry I am a begginer in abstract algebra.

Comment: It's a hint: that $G/C(G)$ having prime order is significant.

Comment: G/C(G) is cyclic (of prime order) implies G is abelian. Proofs to be found on MathStackExchange.

Comment: If you are a beginner in abstract algebra, start reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106163/show-that-every-group-of-prime-order-is-cyclic?rq=1) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ needs to be abelian and therefore we get $G/Z(G) = \{\bar{e}\}$. Why is the quotient group cyclic in your case?