# Show that $(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z, +)$ is the only group of order $5,$ up to renaming the elements in the set.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to prove that there is only one group of order $5$, $(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z, +)$.

I know that there is only one group of every prime order, however I don't know how to prove this particular question. **We're just starting group theory in this class, haven't started anything like Lagrange's Theorem yet.**

So far the only idea I have is to write out every single possible "group" until I get two of the same element in a row or column in each one. That seems incredibly tedious and quite frankly I wouldn't know what all the possibilities would be.

Any advice for tackling this?

Comment: Either do the tendious work or prove it in general: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106163/show-that-every-group-of-prime-order-is-cyclic?rq=1

Comment: You could do an 'easy' version of Lagrange's Theorem for just this case - as shown below.

Comment: I would gladly do the tedious work, I just don't know where to begin. Would I just need to list the five tables corresponding to the five possible inverses of some element a in G, and then show that four of them aren't groups?

Comment: In the title, when you said “remaining the names of”, did you mean “renaming the”?

Comment: Indeed, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Let $e$ be the identity. For some non-identity element $a$, let $A=\{ e,a,a^2,a^3, ...\}$. Let $n$ be the least power of $a$ such that $a^n=e$. Then $|A|=n\ge 2.$

If $A$ contains every element of the group, then the group is cyclic. Otherwise, there is an element $b$ not in this set. We can then let $B=\{ b,ab,a^2b,a^3b,...\}$. It is straightforward to prove that $|B|=n.$

If $A$ and $B$ have an element in common then suppose that $a^ib=a^j$. Multiplying on the left by $a^{-i}$ gives $b=a^{j-i}$, a contradiction. Therefore $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

The group has 5 elements. Repeating this process with any element not in $A$ or $B$ would give a further $n$ elements which is impossible. But it is also impossible for the group to have $2n$ elements.

The only possibility is that the group is the cyclic group of order 5.