# Let $ε$ be the identity of $G$. Prove for $g\in G$ s.t. $g^5=ε$, either $g=ε$, or $ε, g, g^2, g^3, g^4$ are distinct.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $\varepsilon$ be the identity of a group $G$. Prove that if $g\in G$ and $g^5=\varepsilon$, then either $g=\varepsilon$ or $\varepsilon, g, g^2, g^3, g^4$ are distinct.

I don't necessarily want an entire proof, I just don't know how to get started with this proof and the direction I should take to complete the proof.

Comment: Apply Lagrange's theorem to the subgroup generated by $g$.

Comment: 5 is a prime should be a start.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $g$ is not the identity, and two of the given elements are the same, show that $g^r$ is the identity for some $1\le r\le 4$ using the group rules.

Comment: You don't need Lagrange's Theorem, it's completely elementary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that every group of prime order is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106163/show-that-every-group-of-prime-order-is-cyclic). Look at the [top answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106292/104041) in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\epsilon, g, g^2, g^3, g^4$ are not unique and prove that this implies $g=\epsilon$.

Let's look at an example of how this argument would go, say $g^2=g^4$. Denote this common element by $x$. Then, $$\epsilon=xx^{-1}=(g^4)(g^2)^{-1}=g^2.$$
Now you know that $g^2=g^4=\epsilon$, so $\epsilon=g^5=g^4g=\epsilon g=g$.

Adapt this argument to the case where $g^k=g^\ell$ for $0\leq k<\ell\leq 4$.