# Bijection proof

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I got this on an exam and struggled to complete it, could anyone offer a proof? Thanks!

> Let $X$ be a finite set. Let $f: X \longrightarrow X$ be a bijection. For $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, set
>   $$f^n = \underbrace{f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f}_{n \text{ times}}.$$
>
> Prove that there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f^m = \mathrm{Id}_X$.

Answer (score 6):

There are finitely many bijections, so you must have $f_j=f_k$ for some $j\lt k$. Then consider $f_{k-j}$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use superscripts, $f^j$ instead of $f_j$ for the $j$-fold iteration of a function?

Comment: @Michael, yes. When I answered the question, it had not been posted in TeX, and it had fm and fn. On that shaky basis, I thought OP would be more comfortable with $f_m$ than with $f^m$. Perhaps I should have used $f^m$ anyway. If it bothers you, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If you wanted to prove that there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^m (x)=x$ for just one $x\in X$, how would you do it (remember that $X$ is finite)? Next, repeat the argument with $f^m$ taking the place of $f$ (remember that $(f^m)^n=f^{mn}$). An easy induction on the number of elements in $X$. For me, this is the easiest way to see it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple proof is to use Lagrange's theorem: the set of bijections $X\to X$ is a finite group and hence $f^m=\operatorname{id}$ for say $m=n!$, where $n=|X|$.

Comment: Gerry's answer is much more elementary.

Comment: In my exam i got to the point where i figured out that there was a limited number of bijections n! but how do you skip from there to the fact that f^m=id??

Comment: The cyclic subgroup generated by f contains the inverse of f.

Comment: @Katie, that's what [Pete Clark](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/299/pete-l-clark) calls *Lagrange's Little Theorem*: in a finite group of order N, we have $x^N=1$ for every $x$.

Comment: @lhf: Thanks for the plug.  Actually though I reserve LLT for the case of a finite *commutative* group, because in this case one really can carry over the argument from the standard proof of Fermat's Little Theorem.  So far as I know -- and I think we've had a good discussion of this point on this site -- there is not a similarly easy combinatorial proof in the non-commutative case.  (Right?)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, ah, ok, yes, the abelian case has it's own nice proof, probably the one Fermat and Euler used, and certainly the first one I learned in number theory. Yes, we've had this conversation before. I still wish I knew a nice proof in the nonabelian case: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

1. For each $n$, $f^n=\underbrace{f\circ f\circ\ldots \circ f}_{n}$ is a bijection from $X$ to $X$.
2. Are there infinitely many bijections from a finite set to itself?
3. Pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x, f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x), \ldots
$$
This list cannot go on forever, since $X$ is finite.  So it must reach one that has appeared in the list earlier.  Suppose
$$
f(f(f(f(f(f(f(x))))))),
$$
the seventh one, appeared earlier as the third one.  Then
$$
f(f(f(x))) = f(f(f(f(f(f(f(x))))))).
$$
Since $f$ is one-to-one, we can cancel:
$$
x = f(f(f(f(x)))).
$$
But that doesn't mean $f\circ f\circ f\circ f$ is the identity.  It only means that if you apply it to this one element, $x$, you get back $x$, NOT that if you apply it to every element $y$, you'll get back $y$.

So suppose $x$ re-appears in four steps
$$
x \mapsto f(x) \mapsto f(f(x)) \mapsto f(f(f(x))) \mapsto f(f(f(f(x))))
$$
and some other element, $w$, re-appears in six steps:
$$
f(f(f(f(f(f(w)))))) = w.
$$
The smallest common multiple of $4$ and $6$ is $12$, so after $12$ steps, both $w$ and $x$ will re-appear simultaneously.

There are finitely many elements of $X$.  Find the smallest common multiple of the numbers of steps it takes to get them to re-appear.  After that many steps, the all re-appear simultaneously.  So $f$ iterated that many times is the identity function on $X$.