# Original papers on the subject of group actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, notation, group-actions

Does anyone if there are any original paper(s) that first introduced the notion of group action or permutation representation, and who the author(s) were? Any references I have found so far on e.g. Wikipedia are for current textbooks.

I am interested to find out the original motivation for introducing the concept. That is, whether group action was first introduced in its own right as a binary operation, which is a generalisation of the action of a permutation on a set, or whether the representation of an abstract group by a permutation group was considered first, and then the action defined later as an axiomatisation. (I realise these are equivalent concepts, but I am more interested in precisely which came first - of course this may be a 'chicken and egg' situation, but I just thought I would ask.) Many thanks

---

Just to clarify, the 'picture' I have in mind when explaining the possible origin of the notion is this: someone looked at the behaviour of a permutation $\sigma$ acting in the natural way on an element $x$ in a set $X$ to give $\sigma(x)$, with its properties such as $\sigma_1(\sigma_2(x))=(\sigma_1\sigma_2)(x)$, and then decided to generalise this to an arbitrary group by inventing a binary operation and forcing the group elements to obey the same sort of relations as the permutations, i.e. for the 'composition of maps' property $g.(h.x) = (gh).x $.

Comment: Would it be surprising if it went the other way around? It seems possible that "group theory" sprung out of the study of permutations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it all goes back to *Abel, Ruffini, Lagrange* and of course *Galois*, although the notion of a group was not totally formalized at this time. What I am 90% sure about, is that the notion of *group action* (that is *transformation groups*) came before the notion of *abstract group*.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of Ruffini before. I suppose I am thinking more about the more formal definition of a group action as a map $G \times X \rightarrow X$ with the two usual axioms, as opposed to the general idea, which I am sure existed previously in a less formal form.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link to [Arthur Cayley's first paper on group theory](http://sofia.nmsu.edu/~davidp/cayleyrev2.pdf) with comments, in an answer to a [different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory) on MSE.