# Proof of Fermat's little theorem using groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove Fermat's little theorem using groups. Here is my proof:

Let $p$ be a prime. Since all numbers a such that $1\leq a\leq p-1$ are relatively prime
with $p$, they form a group under multiplication modulo $p$.(There is a theorem about
this, that must be true, they should be forming a group). So, let the group be
$G=\{a,a^2,\dots,a^{p-1}\}$ and binary operation is multiplication modulo $p$. Since all
elements of this group are relatively prime with $p$, then any element $a \in G$ is a 
generator of this group, and this group is cyclic. So, we must have $a \cdot a^{p-1}=a \bmod p$. Then multiplying each sides with $a{-1}$ (which exists since this is a group) we get $a^{p-1}=1 \bmod p$.

Is there any mistake in my proof? I appreciate your helps. Thank you

Comment: Knowing that the group is of order $p-1$ is not the same as knowing that the group is generated by a single element. It's true that **this** group is generated by a single element, $a$, but proving that is a bit harder than proving little Fermat...

Comment: Or maybe you mean that $G$ is the subgroup of the full group generated by $a$. It is still not true that if $a$ generates a subgroup, then $a^2$ generates the same subgroup. For example, when $p=2$, the set of powers of $2\equiv 3^2$ is not the same as the set of powers of $3$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out by Thomas Andrews, one cannot assume that $a$ generates the group (extreme example: $a=1$).

However, $a$ does generate a *subgroup*, and the order of that subgroup divides $p-1$. That will yield a proof.

Answer (score 9):

There is an elementary proof, that works for abelian groups, and does not require Lagrange or any facts about group orders.

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$. Let $a \in G$. The map $x \mapsto a x$ is a permutation of $G$. Thus
$$
\prod_{x \in G} x
=
\prod_{x \in G} a x
=
a^n 
\cdot
\prod_{x \in G} x, 
$$
where we have used the fact that $G$ is abelian.

It follows $a^n = 1$.

Comment: [I wish I knew](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory) how to prove that for non-abelian groups without using Lagrange's theorem.

Answer (score 4):

You're close yet you chose to do things harder: you have *a group* of order $\,p-1\,$ so any element to the power the order's group, i.e. to the $\,(p-1)$-th power, is the unity, $\,1\,$

Comment: Here's a little bit more background. For all $a$ in $\mathbb Z_{p}^*$, $\langle a\rangle = \{a^1, a^2, a^3, ...\}$ is a subgroup. By Lagrange's theorem, order of $\langle a\rangle $ must divide $p-1$ i.e., the order of $\mathbb Z_{p}^*$. Thus, $a^{p-1}=1$