# Show that for G be a abelian group, $g \in G, g^m=1$, where $m=|G|$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I am pretty sure there is a name for the following theorem, but unfortunately, I don't known it.

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be a abelian group with $m=|G|$, than for any $g \in G, g^m=1$.

Currently I don't have ideas how to approach a proof of this theorem, and will appreciate any help.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate...

Comment: Why do you require $G$ to be abelian?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a well-known elementary version for the case of abelian groups, that does not appeal to Lagrange's theorem.

Consider
$$
X = \prod_{x \in G} x.
$$
Since $G$ is abelian, the order within the product is immaterial.

Since the map
$$
G \to G, \qquad x \mapsto g x
$$
is a bijection, we have
$$
X = \prod_{x \in G} x = \prod_{x \in G} g x = g^{m} \prod_{x \in G} x = g^{m} X,\tag{X}
$$
where we have used again the fact that $G$ is abelian to take the $g$'s out of the product.

From (X) you get
$$
g^{m} = 1.
$$

Comment: Define "well-known"...

Comment: @user1729, for the sole purpose of this post, I will define as *well-known* something that has already been seen elsewhere on MSE, possibly more than once ;-) I have also taught it for many years, but that clearly does not count.

Comment: @user1729: It is the usual proof given for Euler's Theorem, and even Fermat's Theorem, in elementary number theory courses.

Comment: This is very nice, clear and elementary. +1

Comment: [I wish I knew](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory) how to prove that for non-abelian groups without using Lagrange's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Use Lagrange's theorem:

$$g\in G\;,\;\;|\langle g\rangle|=n:=ord(g)\implies n\mid |G|$$

And then $\,g^k=1\;\;\forall\,k=tn\;,\; t\in\Bbb Z\,$

So your claim isn't true *unless* you either require $\,m\le |G|\,$ or else $\,m=ord(g)\,$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Think about what would happen if you had some $g$ with $g^m$ not equal to $1$