# Showing that $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$ when $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to show that if $a$ is any integer relatively prime to $n$, then $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$, where $\phi(n)$ is Euler's totient function whose value is equal to the number of numbers less than $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$.

This seems number-theoretic, but given the context, is meant to be solved with group theory.  I know that the order of $U(n)$ (the group of all numbers less than and relatively prime to $n$ under multiplication) is $\phi(n)$.  Therefore, for any $g \in U(n)$ we know that $g^{\phi(n)}=1$.  I have been trying to use this fact in my proof.  Clearly $a$ need not be in $U(n)$, but I thought perhaps if it is congruent to a member of $U(n)$ I can get the desired result.  For this reason, I applied the division algorithm to write $a=nm+r$ where $m$ is some integer and $1 \le r \le n-1$, and tried to show that $r$ is relatively prime to $n$, so that $a \equiv r \mod n$.  I do not know that this is the best approach, but no others have borne fruit either.

I'd really appreciate a HINT, as always, on how to prove this.  Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\gcd(a,n) = gcd(a + k\cdot n, n)$ for all $a,\,k,\,n$.

Comment: If $d$ is a common divisor of $r$ and $n$ then $d$ is a divisor of $nm+r=a$, so that $n$ and $a$ cannot be relatively prime. In conclusion, it is true that $r$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: If $d$ is a divisor of both $n$ and $r$, you should be able to show from your equation that $d$ is a divisor of $a$ too. But $a$ and $n$ are coprime, so $d$ must be $1$.

Comment: $U(n)$ should not be thought of as the set of integers smaller than $n$ and coprime to $n$, but rather as the group of units in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4):

The order of any element of a finite group divides the order of the group itself. This follows directly from Lagrange's theorem and considering the cyclic subgroup generated by the element. Therefore, if $a$ is any element of a finite group $G$, then $a^{|G|} = 1$. If you consider the group of integers that are relatively prime to $n$ under multiplication, then this group has $\phi(n)$ elements. Therefore we know that $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$ when $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: I wish I knew a proof of this that does not depend on Lagrange's theorem. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest proof that does not rely on group theory is to consider the map $x \mapsto ax$ on $U(n)$. Since $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime, this map is injective and hence bijective. Therefore $x_1 \cdots x_{\phi(n)}$ is fixed by the map. Now, rearrange and cancel.

Comment: See the second proof in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem#Proofs.

Comment: Or just use gcd characteristics and pigeonhole to show it can't be greater than $\phi(n)$ for the exponent ... Lol