# If $(h,k) = 1$, then $h^{\phi(k)}\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\ k)$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups, totient-function

I have encountered a statement which says: for natural numbers $h$ and $k$ such that $(h,k)=1$,we will have $h^{\phi(k)}\equiv 1(\textrm{mod}\ k)$, where $\phi(k)$ is the Euler's totient function that shows the number of positive integers not exceeding $k$ relatively prime to $k$. I wonder is there any formal theorems that illustrate this statement? And how will this theorem be proved?

I think this statement is related closely with cyclic group in group theory, but I can't think of any useful facts to prove this statement. Thank you very much in advance for any replies!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: It's called Euler's Theorem (one of many theorems meriting that name), and you'll find a proof in every intro Number Theory text ever written, also on one out of every three webpages, and probably in many posts on this website.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem also duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450260/showing-that-a-phin-equiv-1-pmod-n-when-a-and-n-are-relatively-prime?rq=1

Comment: Gcd of powers is related to gcd of base,and modulus since it's always 1 in this case the remainders must be coprime to the modulus, how many unique remainders are there ?

Comment: @Roddy, "gcd of powers", what are you talking about?

Comment: $\gcd(a^n,b)\mid \gcd(a,b)^n$

Comment: That plus there being $\phi(n)$ possible coprime remainders, means by pigeonhole principle that $\{a^0, \ldots , a^{\phi(n)}\}$ contains  two powers giving same remainder ...

Comment: @Roddy, I would not have guessed that that was what you meant. Also, two powers giving same remainder implies $a^r\equiv1$ for some $r$, $1\le r\le\phi(n)$, but doesn't show $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1$.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bad communicator, and verbose. I like this method more, just because it basically generalizes to that point for all gcd's between modulus and base of power.