# Show there exists a fixed positive integer $n$ such that $a^n = e$ for all $a\in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Show there exists a fixed positive integer $n$ such that $a^n = e$ for all $a\in  G$.

We know: $n$ is independent of $a$.

Comment: Such an $n$ is called an *exponent* for the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an outline for an elementary argument that avoids Lagrange's theorem:

- Given $a\in G$, there is $n_a\in\mathbb N$ such that $a^{n_a}=e$.
- $a^{kn_a}=e$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$.
- Consider $n=\operatorname{lcm}_{a\in G} n_a$.

Of course, that $G$ is finite is essential here.

Comment: Lagrange's theorem implies that you can take $n=|G|$ but [I wish I knew](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory) a proof that does not depend on Lagrange's theorem .

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was so similar to yours.  I did show show why $n_a$ existed in case the OP didn't know, but I deleted it anyway.  The proof of Lagrange's theorem doesn't seem so bad.  Why do you want to avoid it?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: For any element $g \in G$, what can you say about $g^{|G|}$?

Comment: So a to any power would be a subgroup within G where the result is the identity?

Comment: @sprgrl11 $a$ to a power is an element, not a subgroup.