# Contraction Mapping, why constant and weak inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, self-learning

From Wikipedia, a **contraction mapping** is a function $f: M \rightarrow M$ on a metric space $(M,d)$ such that there exists a nonnegative real number $k<1$ such that for all $x,y\in M$, 
$$
d \left(f(x),f(y)\right) \leq k \cdot d(x,y). \tag{1}
$$

I have a question that's probably pretty basic since I feel that I just have the wrong intuition for it right now.

Why could the above definition not just be replaced (unless it can be) with a simpler definition like this?:

A function $f: M \rightarrow M$ on a metric space $(M,d)$ is a contraction mapping if and only if 
$$
d \left(f(x),f(y)\right) < d(x,y) \tag{2}
$$
for all $x,y\in M$ (replacing the weak inequality and constant $k$ with just a strict inequality)? This is probably just an intuitive misunderstanding, but to me, it seems like that a contraction map is just a function where given two points, they always get mapped by $f$ to two points that are even closer together.

Comment: On the one hand, you can't have a strict inequality without explicitly demanding that $x\neq y$. That's a little more inconvenient. On the other, more important hand, a weak contraction ($d(f(x),f(y)) < d(x,y)$ for all $x\neq y$) doesn't have as nice properties. A (strong) contraction on a complete space always has a (unique) fixed point. A weak contraction need not have one (but if it has, that is of course unique).

Comment: Oh, ok, I think I get it. So Equation (2) is actually inconsistent since $d(f(x_0),f(x_0)) = d(x_0,x_0) = 0$, so the inequality must be weak. So the implication of Equation (1) is that the images of the two points must always be at least a teeny bit closer than the points are in the domain because of the $k$, but the second form doesn't require this because of the lack of the $k$.

Comment: I was convinced the former was nicer than the latter when proving both types had fixed points (from compact spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer "why is this definition the way it is?" it helps to ask a more basic question: "what is this definition good for?"

The property $d(f(x),f(y))\le kd(x,y)$ (for all $x,y $) implies the existence of a unique fixed point of $f$, provided that $f:X\to X$ is a map on a complete metric space $X$. (As Daniel Fischer said in a comment.) In other words, the equation $f(x)=x$ has a unique solution. This is fantastic, getting the existence of a  solution  of an equation (where $x$ may well be a vector or a function) from  a mild assumption. This theorem is currently high on the list of [overpowered mathematics results](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/555323/103402), whatever that means.

The property $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ (for all $x\ne y$) implies the uniqueness of a fixed point, should it exist. It does not imply existence, and uniqueness with no clue to existence is not nearly as useful. For a concrete example, 
$$f(x)=x-\arctan  x$$
is a map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ which satisfies this property, but has no fixed points.

Comment: Are you sure $f(x)=x-\arctan x$ has no fixed points? I get $x=0$. Perhaps you mean $f(x)=x-\arctan x +\frac \pi 2$.

Answer (score 2):

The main conceptual difference is this: in a contraction, we want that $k$ to be the same, no matter what x and y are. If you just use $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ (whenever $x<>y$), then you have a $k$ for *each* pair -- when this happens, we call f a WEAK contraction.

So $y(x)=x^2$ defined for $0<=x<=1/2$ is a weak contraction, but it is not a contraction!

Comment: This is the exact piece of the puzzle I was missing. Basically strong contractions are required to scale the distance by the same factor everywhere while weak ones dont have the “same factor” requirement.

Answer (score 1):

please note that, the contraction mappings are mainly used for obtaining the fixed point of mappings, which can be further applied to obtain the existence of solutions of differential equations, integral equations etc.. Note that, the condition $$d(f(x),f(y))\leq kd(x,y) \; \forall x,y\in X$$ implies both the existence and uniqueness of fixed point, and so, the existence of solution of various problems including the differential equations, integral equations etc.. But the condition $$d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y) \; \forall x,y\in X,x\neq y$$ can not assure the existence of solution (fixed point). The second condition can be used for existence, but with some additional condition. Although, you can use any of the conditions as your requirements.

Best Wishes