# What is a contraction on a space $(X,d)$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I have been reading some proofs on the elementary theorems of differential equations. One such proof uses the concept of a "contraction". See the definition below.

> **Definition 4** Let $(X,d)$ be a space equipped with a distance function $d$. A function $\Phi:X\to X$ from $X$ to itself is a contraction if there is a number $k\in (0,1)$ such that for any pair of points $x,y\in X$ we have
>   $$d(\Phi(x),\Phi(y))\leq kd(x,y).$$
>   It is important that the constant $k$ is strictly less than one.

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVSbv.png) (Taken from [this pdf](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~troby/Math200S08/existence.pdf).)

To put it into my own words, it seems that a contraction is simply a modified distance function that always yields a value less than the normal distance function for the same set of points. Am I understanding it correctly?

Would someone be able to offer an example of a contraction?

Thank you!

Comment: It was taken from this pdf: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~troby/Math200S08/existence.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Besides the fact that your understanding omits the mapping of points to other points, the existence of $k<1$ such that a certain thing is always less than $k$ is NOT the same as saying that that certain thing is always less than $1$.  For example, consider the function $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$.  Then one has $|f(x)-f(y)|<1\cdot|x-y|$, but there is no number $k<1$ such that for every two points $x,y$ one has $|f(x)-f(y)|\le k|x-y|$.  The reason is that for any proposed value $k<1$, one can find very large values of $x,y$ for which $|f(x)-f(y)|>k|x-y|$ (although $|f(x)-f(y)|$ is still less than $|x-y|$).

Comment: Michael's point is explored in further detail by [this previous Question and Answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556084/contraction-mapping-why-constant-and-weak-inequality).

Comment: I see. So my original statement implied that a contraction means $|f(x) - f(y)| < |x-y|$, but this isn't what the definition says. Introducing the $k < 1$ fundamentally changes the situation. Is that correct?

Comment: @EternusVia : Yes.  It is possible for all members of a set to be less than $1$ even though the set has no upper bound less than $1$.  The simplest example of that is the set of all numbers less than $1$, which has no upper bound less than $1$. The definition of "contraction" requires the set $\displaystyle \left\{ \frac{d(f(x),f(y))}{d(x,y)} : x,y\in X\ \&\ x\ne y\right\}$ to have an upper bound less than $1$. For some metric spaces $X$ and some functions $f:X\to X$ every member of that set is less than $1$ but the set has no upper bound less than $1$.  Those functions are not contractions.

Answer (score 1):

No, a contraction is not a metric(aka distance function). What a contraction does is bring every pair of points closer together(in the implicit metric). For instance, $f(x)=x/2$ is a contraction in the euclidean metric of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Interesting. So If I have a = 2 and b = 6, the distance between them is 4. But if I apply f(x) to a and b, the new distance is 2. Thus f(x) qualifies as a contraction, because 2 < k*4 where 0 < k < 1. On the other hand, the function g(x) = 2x is not a contraction. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct, more precisely one possible $k$ for $f(x)=x/2$ is $1/2$. Hence every distance is at least halved. $f(x)=2x$ is not since $d(f(0),f(1)) = 2 d(0,1)$.

Comment: I see! One might dub $f(x) = 2x$ an expansion. Thank you again.