# Use Direct Proof to Prove: If $A\cup B = A$, then $B\subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I started with:

> Assume $A\cup B = A$, then $x\in A \cup B$.
>
> Without loss of generality, let $x \in A$.

However, at this point I am not sure what to do.

**Note:** In the textbook, they use proof by contrapositive, but I want a direct proof.

Comment: You're trying to prove something about $B$, so you should probably start with $x \in B$. And as written, you're concluding something about $x$ before you define it; you should start with "Assume $A \cup B + A$ and let $x \in ...$."

Comment: For any $x$, if $x\in B$, then $x\in A\cup B$, then $x\in A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Along the lines of @T.Bongers's comment:

> Let $x \in B$.
>
> Then $x \in A\cup B$ (by definition of union).
>
> By hypothesis $A \cup B=A$.
>
> Therefore $x \in A$.
>
> Since $x$ was arbitrary, we have shown that for *any* $x \in B$, $x$
>   is also an element of $A$.
>
> It follows that $B \subseteq A$ by the definition of subset.

Comment: Couldn't we also conclude that $A \subseteq B$?

Comment: It does seem that way at first, but just because every element of $x$ is in A does not mean that there could not exist an element of $A$ which is NOT in B. For example, let A be the set of plants, and B be the set of cacti -- then a eucalyptus is in A but not B. The proof given above does not contradict this, since every x considered is a cactus.

Comment: @ZoomBee For a more "mathy" example, consider any non-empty set $A$ and let $B=\emptyset$. Then $A\cup B=A$ and, trivially, $B\subseteq A$, but it is not at all possible that $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: How do you guys approach these problems? I am having trouble with where I need to start. For example, I'm currently working on this problem Prove the following: If $A \cap B = A \cap C$ and $A \cup B = A \cup C$, then $B = C$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/555663/327486

Comment: @ZoomBee The statement is not symmetric or "indifferent" between A and B. Similarly the proof is not symmetric or indifferent. in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

$\{ x: x \in A \ \text{or}  \ x \in B\} = \{ x: x \in A \}$, so $x  \in A \cup B \Longrightarrow x \in A$.

Thus, $\{x \in A \Longrightarrow x \in A\} \ \land \ \{x \in B \Longrightarrow x \in A\} $ implies $B \subseteq A$

Answer (score 0):

$A\cup B=A$ iff there does not exist an element of $B$ not in $A$ iff $B$ is a subset of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A\cup B=A$ , then every element of the union of $A$ and $B$ is an element of $A$.   Now every element of $B$ is *something because of reasons*, so therefore the assumption infers that every element of $B$ would be an element of $A$.  $$A\cup B=A \implies B\subseteq A$$

$\Box$

---

More directly: Because *of some statement* by definition, then if $A\cup B=A$ is assumed we may infer $B\subseteq A$.

$\Box$