# Killing a butterfly with a bazooka

Tags: big-list

Let $n\ge3$. Prove that $\sqrt[n]2\notin\Bbb Q$.

Let us suppose that $\sqrt[n]2=p/q$, that is $2q^n=p^n$, so $q^n+q^n=p^n$, against FLT.

Do you know similar examples, in which simple problems are solved using huge weapons (maybe in a elegant way)?

Comment: That's the first example that pops into my head!

Comment: I like the title lol

Comment: Fabulous. Now we need to find a similar proof for $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this has no... I'm not sure what exactly, but they have none of it.

Comment: Possible bazookas are the four-colour-theorem or the classification of finite simple groups - now I still have to find a suitable butterfly

Comment: The common saying is to kill a fly with a bazooka, but since problems in mathematics are prettier, we have the butterfly. Is this right, OP?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Here's more: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555316/what-are-the-most-overpowered-theorems-in-mathematics

Comment: And here's some more! https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich We have such a proof for $\sqrt{2}$. If it would be rational, then the right angled triangle with rational sides $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2},2$ would have area $1$, so $1$ would be a congruent number, which contradicts Tunnel's theorem.

Comment: I think should not kill butterfly ..let them live

Comment: @Metric: that's right!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Killer of joy, reporting for duty. But Hagen von Eitzen's comment captures the essence of my objection; this question is an invitation to showcase our favourite bazooka's by shooting them at arbitrary innocent butterflies. Too broad.

Comment: There's Direchlet's proof that there are an infinite number of primes via complex integration: https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/Courses/Chapter3.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Every bounded entire complex valued function on the complex plane misses three values in the range and, therefore, is constant by Picard's theorem.