# Anyone has a good recommendation of a free pdf book on group theory?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources

Anyone has a good recommendation of a free pdf book on group theory?

I am specially interested in its application for computer science, however, I do not want it to be less mathematically rigorous just because of that.

I found one that was good, but it only dealt with commutative groups throught the text :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used [this](http://abstract.ups.edu/) (Judson) in my Algebra class. It's pretty good and offers numerous computational exercises using Sage and has sections on cryptography and other computational topics. I enjoyed it.

Note that this text covers more than just group theory and goes into rings, fields, modules, etc. It is meant as a first (and second) course in Algebra text.

Answer (score 4):

If you are fearless, Milne's notes on group theory are pretty good (they are meant to a first year graduate-level course in mathematics): http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/gt.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever seen [this](http://books.google.at/books?id=mXtUAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)?

Schaum's outline of theory and problems of group theory

Comment: I don't think this book is available for free online, and if it is then it probably shouldn't be. However, the author, B.Baumslag, is a very good group-theorist from the golden age of groups. His brother, G.Baumslag, was one of the leading lights during this era. New York would be a different place without G.Baumslag...

Answer (score 2):

There are online copies of Artin's Algebra 2nd Ed