# Looking for group theory exercises

Tags: group-theory, book-recommendation, online-resources

I'd like to have, please, some recommendation for free sources for group theory exercises with solutions. I have looked online but couldn't find some good resources.

Thank you.

Comment: [RealNotComplex](realnotcomplex.com)

Comment: Art of Problem Solving?

Comment: [Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/courses/group-theory/)

Comment: Can I really learn with Brilliant for university level?

Comment: Try https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-theory

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to freely borrow  from your local or university library? Have you tried interlibrary loans? **I own both books beneath that include solutions to *every* exercise, *FREE OF CHARGE*.**

| Title | Author | Publication Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [*Schaum's Outline of Group Theory*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/629767) | B. Baumslag, B. Chandler | 1968 |
| *Discovering Group Theory: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics* | Tony Barnard, Hugh Neill | 2016 |