# Proving that $(aH)^{m} = H$ for any $a \in G$, with $H\triangleleft G$ and $(G:H)=m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I've seen this in various proofs, but never justified. I'm guessing it's something very simple, but I haven't been able to do it so far.

Let $G$ be a group of finite order $n$ and $H\triangleleft  G$ such that $(G:H)=|G/H|=m$. I want to prove that $(aH)^{m} = H$ for any $a \in G$.

I know that $(aH)^m=a^mH$ and that $a^n=e$ for any element of $G$. These two facts seem to be the key, but I don't see exactly how.

Comment: are you aware of Lagrange's Theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First consider the following lemma:

> Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$. Then $g^n=e$ for any $g\in G$.

This follows from Lagrange's Theorem and you can find the full proof here:

[Does someone know why raising the element of a group to the power of the order of the group yields the identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629725/does-someone-know-why-raising-the-element-of-a-group-to-the-power-of-the-order-o)

Now back to your case. Since $H$ is normal in $G$ then $G/H$ is a group. Also the order of $G/H$ is equal to $(G:H)$. Apply the lemma above to $G/H$ to get the result.

Comment: So let me see if I got it right: $aH \in G/H$ and $|G/H|=m$. Thus, using the lemma you stated, $(aH)^m = e$. But the identity $e$ of $G/H$ is $H$.

Comment: @XicoSim Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

G/H is a quotient group of order m. So $\forall aH\in G/H, ord(aH)|m$.
Then $(aH)^m=(aH)^{ord (aH)}=H=1_{G/H}$.