# In a finite group, the equation $x^m=e$ has $m$ solutions for each positive $m$ that divides the order of the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that in a finite cyclic group $G$ of order $n$ written multiplicatively the equation $x^m=e$ has $m$ solutions $x\in G$ for each positive $m$ that divides $n$

I am having trouble understanding how to do this without using Lagrange theorem. I could really use some help here

Comment: Something is wrong with the statement. Check it. For example in the Klein four group the equation $x^2=e$ has four solutions, not two as you are claiming.

Comment: Maybe it is "at least $m$ solutions"?

Comment: As a general rule, you should put the question in the body of the post. The title should just indicate roughly what it is about.

Comment: @DerekHolt Actually, it's not a problem if the title indicates *exactly* what the question is. Saves people the trouble of opening it. But I agree the question should contain the question.

Comment: [I wish I knew](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory) how to prove the case $m=n$ without using Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You may have missed that the group is cyclic.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, in the original version of the question that key bit was left out :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can assume that $G = \mathbb{Z}_n$, the group of integers modulo $n$ under addition. So that we don't get confused, we represent the group operation of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as addition. Your question asks for the number of solutions of the equation $mx \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$, where $0 \leq x < n$. Since $m\mid n$, we can write each such $x$ in the form $y(n/m)+z$, where $0 \leq z < n/m$ and $0 \leq y < m$. We have $mx = ny+mz \equiv mz \pmod{n}$, so the solutions are $z = 0$ and $0 \leq y < m$, of which there are exactly $m$.