# Order of any element divides the order of the group proof

Tags: group-theory

> Show that the order of any element $g \in G$ divides $n$, where $n$ is the order of a group $G$.

So far I have shown that:
$G$ - finite group and let $g \in G$, therefore, the order of the subgroup generated by $g$ equals the order of $g$. Using Lagrange's Theorem we get that the order of $g$ divides $n$, which we had to prove.
Is this a valid proof or am I missing something? Any ideas?

Comment: The proof is Ok

Comment: [I wish I knew](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory) how to prove this *without* Lagrange's theorem.