# Why is $a^{\# G}=e$ where $a$ is any element of group $G$ and $\# G$ is the number of elements and $e$ is the identity element?

Tags: group-theory

Why is $a^{\# G}=e$ where $a$ is any element of group $G$ and $\# G$ is the number of elements and $e$ is the identity element?

I am reading Sternberg's "Group Theory and Physics."

Comment: This is a consequence of Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just looked at wikipedia article on Lagrange's theorem and there was the answer. Now, I know what cyclic subgroup is.

Comment: Yeah, I took a quick look at the book you are reading, and it seems like it skips several important things in order to quickly get to those parts of interest to physics.

Comment: This doesn't directly address your question, but the notation $|G|$ is the standard notation for the number of elements in $G$, which we refer to as the *order* of $G$. I've actually never seen the notation $\#G$.

Comment: @manthanomen It is the notation used in the book mentioned, and while not common, it does pop up here and there (more commonly for just sets than groups though).

Comment: I suggest you read the first chapter ot two of any introductory book on groups, especially on the topic of finite groups.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory