# Proof Help: Order of element divides order of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm stuck in proving that the order of an element divides the order of the group.

I've already proved Lagrange's theorem that for $H<G, |H|||G|$

And I know that for any $a\epsilon G, |a|=|<a>|$

The problem is that though I know this for a fact, I need to prove that the order of the element equals the order of the cyclic subgroup it generates but how do i prove this result to finally conclude that the order of a divides G using lagrange?

Please help.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=\operatorname{ord}a$. Then $a^n=e$ and $a^k\neq e$ if $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$. But then $\langle a\rangle=\{e,a,a^2,\ldots,a^{n-1}\}$ and therefore $\operatorname{ord}\langle a\rangle=n=\operatorname{ord}a$.

Comment: Then, do we assume by definition that $<a>= {e,a,a^2,...,a^{n-1}}$? And also, you assumed that $a^k$ does not equal e for all $k\epsilon {1,2,....3,n-1}$ because by definition n is the smallest positive integer such that $a^n = e$? Thanks

Comment: No, I did not assume that $\langle a\rangle=\{e,a,\ldots,a^{n-1}\}$. But it is obvous that $\langle a\rangle\supset\{e,a,\ldots,a^{n-1}\}$ and since $\{e,a,\ldots,a^{n-1}\}$ is a group and $\langle a\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup containing $a$… The answer to your second question is affirmative.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand. Does this mean I'd have to prove that $\langle a\rangle=\{e,a,\ldots,a^{n-1}\}$ and if so, how? I'd also have to prove that $<a> $ is the smallest subgroup containing a but that is obvious because the group has to satisfy the closure property

Comment: @A.Asad *By definition*, $\langle a\rangle$ is the smallest subgrout containing $a$. It is easy to see that $\{e,a,\ldots,a^{n-1}\}$ is the smallest subgroup containing $a$ and therefore that it is equal to $\langle a\rangle$.

Comment: In laymen's terms you are seeing that $a$ generates a cyclic subgroup of $G$. The order of a cyclic subgroup is the order of it's generator, and since $<a> < G$ you have that the order of $<a>$ divides the order of $G$ by Lagrange. Also the order of $<a>$ is the order of $a$.

**edit:** oh woops I see now your actual question seems to be how to prove $|a| = |<a>|$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first part of your question comes really quickly,

$$|a| = |<a>|\,\bigg|\,|G|$$

$<a>$ is a subgroup so it's order must divide the order of the group (by Lagrange)

It seems like you are really asking why $|a| = |<a>|$

To see this recall that $$<a> = \{a^k \ | \ k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

When $ |a| < \infty,$ $$\  a^{n_1} = a^{n_2} \iff n_1 = n_2 \mod |a| $$

$ \\ $

In particular, $\{a^k \ | \ k \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{e=a^0,a,a^2,a^3,\ldots,a^{|a|-1}\}$

which has $|a|$ elements.