# Proof Verification for Lagrange's Theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am reading *I.N.Herstein-Topics in Algebra*

**Question:**

> For $G$ a finite group. Let $|G|=n$, then $O(a)|n \enspace \forall
>  a\in G$.

*Note:*
I have already proved that if $G$ is a finite group, then $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^N=e \enspace \forall a \in G$ and $N\leq n$.

**Proof:**
Suppose $\exists a\in G$ and a minimal $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a^m=e$ and $m\nmid n$.

Given $G$ is finite. Therefore, we have $$a^n=e\\\text{By using division algorthim,}\enspace  n=km+r\enspace\text {for some k}\in \mathbb{N} \\ \implies a^{n-km}.\{a^m\}^k=e \\ \implies a^{n-km}.e=e \\ \implies a^{n-km}=e$$
This Contradicts minimality of $m$.

Therefore, $O(a)|n \enspace \forall a\in G$.
This also proves that $N|n$.

Is My proof Correct? Any Improvements and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but how does the note you wrote prove that $a^n=e$? The note says you only know that there is $N\leq n$ such that $a^N=e$. It doesn't simply imply that $a^n=e$.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the correction. I got it. $a^n=e$ is not implied by the fact that $a^N=e$ but it is implied by the finiteness of $G$.

Comment: It is true that if $G$ is finite then $a^{|G|}=e$ but the proof is not so trivial. Do you know about Lagrange's theorem? That if $H$ is a subgroup then $|H|$ divides $|G|$? Everything follows from this, including what you need to prove.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory

Comment: @Mark I Know Lagrange's Theorem. But I haven't proved it yet. and Herstein asks to prove the above fact without the use of Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: Ok, I'm just confused how do you know that $a^n=e$ then. The proof I know actually follows from the fact that the order of $a$ must divide $n$ (if $n=O(a)\times d$ then obviously $a^n=(a^{O(a)})^d=e^d=e$), which is what you need to prove. Maybe there are other proofs, I don't know.

Comment: @Mark I have concluded by the help of examples. But I think I have overkilled it there itself.

Comment: You cannot start with $a^n=e$.

Comment: Well, examples are not a proof. To be honest I have never seen a proof of the statement you want to prove without Lagrange's theorem.