# If $G$ is a finite group and $g \in G$, then $O(\langle g\rangle)$ is a divisor of $O(G)$

Tags: group-theory

Does this result mean:

1. Given any finite group, if we are able to find a cyclic group out of it (subgroup), then the order of the cyclic group will be a divisor of the original group.

If I am right in interpreting it, can one suggest an example of highlighting this? And also make me understand the *possible practical uses* of this result. It surely looks interesting

Thanks

Soham

Comment: This is a special case of Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: yes, I am sorry, I corrected it.Thanks

Comment: Yes, I understand it follows from Lagrange's theorem, the proof doesnt look complicated if one knows LT. I was just thinking if my understanding is in sync

Comment: yes, you understand correctly

Comment: great, so if that is so, can you give me an example of it. Preferably taking a set in complex numbers.

Comment: Finding a proof that does not need the full Lagrange theorem is my favorite question: [Is Lagrange's theorem the most basic result in finite group theory?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory).

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28317/how-to-prove-the-following-about-a-group-g

Comment: By the way, $O(G)$ is not a standard notation for the order of $G$. It is better to use $|G|$, because $O(G)$ is often used to mean something more complicated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a finite group $G$ and you take any element $g\in G$. Then $\langle g \rangle$ is a *subgroup* of $G$. Then, as mentioned in the comment by anon, you can apply [Lagrange's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) to get the conclusion that you want.

As an example of this, you could consider the [symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) $S_5$. You pick a random element $\sigma \in S_5$, for example $\sigma = (1, 2, 4)$. Then you get the  subgroup
$$
\langle \sigma\rangle = \{(1,2,4), (1, 4, 2), (1) \}.
$$
Hence the order of $\langle \sigma\rangle$ is $3$, and indeed 3 is a divisor in  $O(S_5) = 5! = 120$.

You ask in the comment above about an example with a subgroup of the complex numbers. Consider $z = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{15}}$. Then you have the group $G = \langle z\rangle$ (under multiplication). This group has order $15$. Can you find/write down the elements?)Now take $w= e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$. Then $\langle w\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order ... ( I will let you think about that).

As an application of this someone else might have something helpful to say.

Comment: order <w> = 3 and yes, proving it as a subgroup is easy, I guess.

Comment: Additionally, if O(H) = m/gcd(m,i) here m = 15, but what is i? The generator is $z^3$ isnt it?

Comment: You are right: the generator for $H = \langle w \rangle$ is $z^3$. I am not sure that I understand your formula.

Comment: Its a theorem, it says, if G is a cyclic group with order m and H is  subgroup (obviously subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic and let its generator be z^i) then O(H)= m/gcd(m,i)

Comment: Ok, so you have $m =15$, $i = 3$, so the order of $\langle w\rangle = \frac{15}{\gcd(15,3)} = \frac{15}{3} = 5$.

Comment: Of course, how asinine of me, for a moment I was thinking gcd(15,3) is 1

Answer (score 2):

An application of this result is the formula
$$
\sum_{d\mid n} \phi(d) = n
$$
which can be estabilished by considering the cyclic group of order $n$: every element in this group has an order which is a divisor of $n$ and for every divisor $d$ of $n$ there are exactly $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$.

A consequence of this formula is that [finite multiplicative subgroups of a field are cyclic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic). In particular, the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic.

A simpler but very important consequence of the theorem is that groups of prime order are cyclic.