# Let G be a cyclic group of order 42. How to find the number of the elements of order 6, and the number of elements of order 7?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order 42. How to find the nos of elements of order 6?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

Since $G$ is cyclic. It has a unique cyclic subgroup of order $d$, for each $d|42$.

If $a,b\in G$ bot have order $7$, they generate a cyclic subgroup of order $7$, that means that $(a)=(b)$ by uniqueness. Now, any element except the identity in this subgroup must have order $7$, since $7$ is prime (by an identical argument to the one below). So there are $6$ elements of order $7$.

On the other hand, consider the cyclic subgroup of order $6$. A cyclic group of order $6$ has $\varphi(6)=2$ generators (where $\varphi$ is Euler's Totient function). Since all cyclic groups are isomorphic, that means the cyclic subgroup also must have $2$ generators.

Comment: All this is reflected in the identity $n = \sum_{d \mid n} \phi(d)$.

Comment: @lhf Your identity blown up my mind.

Comment: @peterh, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190560/589